# Systick Interrupt : concept and purpose

Tags: timer, arm, stm32, interrupt

I am taking a beginners course on Stm32 and recently learned about Interrupts and also about the Systick.

I understand the concept of GPIO Interrupts. For example: a Button is pressed, that press is "detected" and a function is triggered.

However I don't understand the concept of a Systick-Interrupt and what it can do.

I used the Systick to create a delay function like this:

```
void systickDelayMs(int delay){
    //-------Configure Systick-------
    /* Reload with number of clocks per milisecond */
    SysTick->LOAD = SYSTICK_LOAD_VAL;
    /*Clear systick current value register*/
    SysTick->VAL = 0;
    /*Enable systick and select internal clock source */
    SysTick->CTRL = CTRL_ENABLE |  CTRL_CLKSRC;
    for(int i=0; i<delay ; i++){
        /*Wait until the countflag is set*/
        while((SysTick-> CTRL & CTRL_COUNTFLAG)== 0){}
    }

    SysTick->CTRL = 0;

}
```

Now what can a Systick Interrupt do that such a Systick delay function cannot?

Comment: with many things you have the choice of polling vs an interrupt.  You can sit in the look to kill time, but the processor is just doing that. If you use an interrupt then you can do other things while that time is ticking down.   You can also use the systick interrupt for task switching in your scheduler, when the interrupt happens change state and return to one of the other tasks.

Comment: You could just as easily poll the gpio input to see if the button was pressed.  In the case of buttons you do not want to use an interrupt for gpio, you will get bouncing and that can be bad in many ways.  Actually want to use a systick or other timer interrupt to sample the gpio pin to avoid the bouncing that can cause havoc in your system.  but assuming you solve that, you can poll the gpio pin or interrupt on it, you can poll the timer or interrupt on it,  your choice if you can understand one you can understand the other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the most part, you can treat it like just another basic timer, it's just a part of the core and doesn't require activating clock for external peripheral, and it's standardized across the same cores, even if they are in other MCUs. Just like with any timer, you can do polling or interrupt. So, your question effectively boils down to "timer with polling vs timer with interrupt". Which is very close to "what is the use for interrupts in Timers".

If you do polling, like in your delay implementation, your MCU is sitting in a while loop and waiting for something to happen to break out of that loop. Your MCU can't do anything in its main execution sequence - only an interrupt can take over.

If you use interrupt approach, your program execution doesn't stop when you set up SysTick parameters and activate its interrupt. Your further code is executed immediately, but when certain set amount of time passes, an interrupt fires, so wherever your MCU was and whatever it was doing, it pauses it and does whatever interrupt function is (but if MCU already was handling some interrupt, only higher priority interrupt will be fired immediately). Similarly to basic timers, one of the most common uses for it is scheduling.

Specifically for SysTick, it's common to have a 1ms interrupt and a variable associated with it (static - global for your SysTick.c, wrapped up into functions to return it). Every 1ms it gets incremented by 1 (32-bit variable will overflow after almost 50 days). One of the uses of that is, for example, that you can check the value of that variable to estimate passed time. Much like [Arduino's millis()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/). Obviously, you are free to use it any way you want. It's your piece of hardware, and if your algorithm finds some other use for it, you're welcome to do it, although it's more common to leave SysTick ticking every 1ms, while custom scheduling is left for basic timers (e.g. TIM6/TIM7).

Here is my implementation on registers on STM32F746, [systick.c](https://github.com/ellectroid/STM32F746-CMSIS-RCC-Max-Freq-SysTick-Basic-Timer-Demo/blob/main/Src/systick.c):

```
#include "systick.h"

volatile static uint32_t SYSTEM_MS; //49 days

void systick_setup(uint32_t sys_freq) {
    SysTick->LOAD = (sys_freq / 1000U) - 1U; //1ms tick
    SysTick->VAL = 0x00; //explicitly set start value (undefined on reset)
    SysTick->CTRL |= (1U << SysTick_CTRL_TICKINT_Pos) | (1U << SysTick_CTRL_CLKSOURCE_Pos); //enable systick interrupt, source processor clock
    SCB->SHPR[8] = 0U; //set SysTick interrupt priority (default: 0, the highest)
    SysTick->CTRL |= (1U << SysTick_CTRL_ENABLE_Pos); //enable SysTick
}

void SysTick_Handler(void) {
    SYSTEM_MS++;
}

uint32_t millis(void){
    return SYSTEM_MS;
}

void system_msdelay(uint32_t delay_ms){
    uint32_t end = millis() + delay_ms;
    while(millis()!=end); //not <, because overflow
}
```

Comment: I've voted +1, but I will say that running the systick 1000 times a second is a bit crazy.  On some slower microcontrollers the core will spend more time handling the clock interrupt than anything else!  100/second (10ms period) is very widespread and normal nowadays, and 50 or 60Hz used to be more common.

Comment: @TomV by my rough estimations even on 16MHz internal clock it takes only up to 0.3% of CPU time (16 cycles to enter interrupt, 16 to exit, a few to increment the variable). 40 cycles / 16000 cycles per ms at 16MHz gives 0.0025 or 0.25%. Even arduino does update its counter every millisecond. I'd say it starts to matter if your MCU clock is 1MHz or below.

Comment: Does SysTick_Handler excutes every one mS to increment the tick? doesn't it really waste of bandwidth and cpu power?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd yes it does, but already at 16MHz it's almost negligibly little. Anything above and you can consider it a de-facto zero overhead. If you have down to single cycle timing requirement (if that's the case, you should actually ramp up CPU clock), you can always set systick interrupt to lower priority than timing-critical part. Even still, for almost all cases it's negligible. And it's actually 12 cycles to enter interrupt, 12 to exit (spent some nights reading cortex m7 architecture reference manual and related stuff)

Comment: Thx, But why M7?  O_O You've answer right before me one time, I'm sorry for asking again, again thank you so much.

Comment: Because I have an M7 board to play with. This discussion applies to all Cortex-M tho, there is nothing specific about M7 in this context. I just said I studied M7 architecture extensively lately.

Comment: Great answer! I've wondered about why SysTick was its own dedicated timer while there were "Basic Timers" like TIM6, and never considered that SysTick would run constantly, in a loop, at 1 ms, with a software based scheduling system on top of it using a "system time variable" that is incremented by the SYSTICK interrupts. wouldn't have realized that without your answer!